# Plotting a two lists generated after running a for loop

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

So i had to model and solve a harmonic oscillator, being driven by a random driving force. I have managed to finish that and my program is:

```
k = 1; (* spring constant *) 
For[i = 0,
 i < 10,
 i++,
 randforce = RandomVariate  [NormalDistribution[0, 2]];
 lis2 = Table[randforce, i];
 p = NDSolve[{y''[x] + k*y[x] + randforce == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 50}];
 Y[x_] = y[x] /. p;
 list1 = Table[Y[i], {i, 0, 50, 1}];
 Print[randforce, i];
 Print[i, "th", " ", "root mean square", " ", RootMeanSquare[N[list1, 6]]];
 Print[i, "th", " ", "mean displacement", " ", Mean[N[list1, 4]]]
]
```

Trying to plot list 1 vs list 2 using ListPlot but doesnt seem to work. Any other ideas or modifications i can make in the program so that i can do this?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "plotting list 1 vs list 2 using `ListPlot`"? Did you do `ListPlot[Transpose[{list1, list2}]]`? You should include that code in your post, too.

Comment: In addition, I don't even *see* a list 2. By the way, I have made edits to your post: I have formatted your code in code blocks (please do this in the future: see the grey question mark at then right of the editing toolbar for help); I have also added semicolons at the end of the `Print` statements. otherwise they would have been "multiplied" together, which I assume you didn't want. Finally: can you please explain what your code is supposed to do (specifically: do you really want to regenerate `lis2` every step of the `For` loop?) and what list 2 is supposed to be?

Comment: Do you realize the `i` inside your `Table` is a different variable from the `For` loop `i`?  Your `lis2` is a length `i` list ( the `For` loop `i` ) with the same random number repeated. `list1` is a length 50 list.  I cant see what sense there is to plot `lis2` against `list1`.

Comment: You'll need to give a more detailed description of what the code is supposed to be doing, the code itself is rather strange and it's difficult to interpret the intention.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you are after..

```
k = 1;(*spring constant*)
result = Table[
   randforce = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2]];
   p = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + k*y[x] + randforce == 0,
      y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 50}];
   rms = RootMeanSquare[Table[p[j], {j, 0, 50, 1}]];
   mean = Mean[Table[p[j], {j, 0, 50, 1}]];
   {randforce, rms, mean}, {i, 100}];

ListPlot[{result[[All, {1, 2}]], result[[All, {1, 3}]]}]
```

[image]